# google.maps.places.Autocomplete - What are the SKUs generated

Tags: autocomplete

I want to know what are the SKUs charged for google.maps.places.Autocomplete.
As per the google document, sessions are managed automatically by the widget. 
There are some scenarios where Autocomplete doesn't give suggestion. In those cases what SKU is charged?

We are getting following SKUs billing report.

1. Autocomplete (included with Places Details)
2. Autocomplete without Places Details – Per Session
3. Autocomplete – Per Request

Why are we getting both Autocomplete without Places Details – Per Session and Autocomplete – Per Request

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, below are examples how they are different

1. Autocomplete (included with Places Details): user types "australia", makes a selection, the system displays Place Details.
2. Autocomplete without Places Details – Per Session: user types "australia", makes a selection
3. Autocomplete – Per Request: user types "australia", and not make any selection